# Confusion about dimension of Lie algebras, and 'isomorphism between Lie algebras'

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras, group-isomorphism, linear-groups

I am following [these lecture notes-](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~agk22/mfds.pdf) and the Theorem 1.16 on page 12 reads

> Suppose that $G ⊂ GL(n, R)$ is a subgroup and an embedded submanifold of $GL(n, R)$, and smooth structure on G is defined by the log-charts. Then the map
>   $ξ ∈ \mathbf{g} → X_ξ ∈ l(G)$ **is an isomorphism of the Lie algebras**, where the Lie bracket on g is
>   the Lie bracket of matrices (as in Theorem 1.7)

Note that $l(G)$ here mans the set of left invariant vector fields.

I don't get what the isomorphism is between. The only groups mentioned are $GL(n,R)$ and the subgroup $G$. But in general, $G$ can have a lower dimension than $GL(n,R)$ e.g. take U(2) of dimension 4, SU(3) of dimension 3. Then the corresponding lie algebras have dimensions 4 and 3, and so canto be isomorphic. So whih are the isomorphic lie algebras?

Some notation:

$\xi \in \mathbf{g}$ i.e. is an element of the lie algebra (though I am not sure if it here refers to the lie algebra of G or GL(n,R).

$X_\xi$ is defined at the vector field coorresponding to taking:

- The left invariant diffeomorphism $L_g:h\in G \rightarrow gh \in G$
- Which has a corresponding differential $(dL_g)_e : T_eG \rightarrow T_gG$
- Then $X_\xi : h\in G \rightarrow (dL_h)_e \xi \in T_h G$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an isomorphism from $\mathfrak g$ (the Lie algebra of $G$) onto the Lie algebra $l(G)$ of all left-invariant vector fields in $G$.